# What's After ranking with low difficulty keyword?

Tags: backlinks, ranking, google-sandbox

I heard and experience that, new blogs can not rank on high difficulty keyword, in the name of "Untrust", gooogle keeps the new website on hold, which are defined as - `Google Dancing` or `Google Sandbox`, so the remedy to get over this for the new blogs is that they should go for low difficulty keyword.

Well, I am targeting new website, which has visibly no backlink, writing about low difficulty keyword, and my website ranks for the low difficulty keyword.

1. What's next, can it next target high difficulty keyword?
2. What's the difference between new blog - targeting directly high diff keyword without any previous rank on any keyword, and targeting high diff keyword with ranking in low diff keyword  - - - does ranking in low diff keyword help anyhow targeting high diff keyword, if so, how ?

Please reply, I want someone having enough experience to reply this.

Comment: It looks like you have been reading some very old SEO articles if they are talking about the "Google Dance" or the "Google Sandbox."   Your takeaway to start with long tail, low difficulty keywords is still good advice, but you should find some more current sources of SEO information.

Comment: thanks for your clarification, well if possible could you please give some link - as comment, SEO tricks does not work, there's no one want to stay behind, so everyone optimizes as much as possible. And you are saying there much more latest working strategy, could you please provide some valid, reliable source

Comment: Have you tried reading through the commonly repeated questions here on this site?  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Trebor Sorry to say honestly, I could only find some old answers, if you could please give me any valid recent answer

Comment: Some of the old answers here on StackExchange are still good answers. // SEO is important, but nowhere near as important as producing content that answers your website visitors' questions or solves their problems.

Comment: This classic thing, I also believe, not too care about Search Engines - provide value though my blog. But what is "KeyWord Difficulty" meaning, simply does it mean that, it is established piece of content, which users usually visit and trust and hence it is ranked, and my article is not ranked because Google is not getting valid signal to where to place my link? If that's the case - another way of saying this is that - you have to simply replace someone to get your place, and some test of time, leap of faith to continue creating better content

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some basics.

**Quality Rater Guidelines**

Make sure you read Google's own [Quality Raters Guidelines](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/guidelines.raterhub.com/en//searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf) QRG This is an invaluable resource on how Google spot checks pages for quality.  Google has 1,000's of spot checkers around the world checking the quality of pages and sites using these guidelines.  This is far more valuable than the hundreds of SEO "experts" selling you something.

**Expertness, Authority and Trustworthiness**

I would recommend you research what is commonly referred to as E.A.T.  [Marie Haynes](https://www.mariehaynes.com/eat/) has some good information on EAT and how it relates to the Google Quality Rater's Guidelines.  However, you can always use the QRG docs to better understand E.A.T.

It will be very hard for a new website to outrank an older website for highly competitive keywords.  It's not impossible, but your competition has the advantage of having already been establishing their E.A.T. before you launched your website.

**Google "Tastes" your web pages**

Google will periodically move your new pages to the top of the SERPs to "[taste](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125344/does-google-limit-how-much-traffic-it-sends-to-a-domain-via-search-results/125352#125352)" if your content appeals to users and answers questions.  How users respond to those taste tests will impact whether or not your page stays towards the top, or gets pushed back down.

**SEO is fluid, but always wants to answer the users question**

I've seen websites with what I perceive as having low E.A.T. still rank well, over sites that do have good E.A.T.  However, it doesn't seem to last very long.  So, when you rank well, don't assume it's because you finally mastered SEO.  It could simply be that Google has been tasting your website.

Lastly, Google's algorithms have hundreds of ranking factors that are being tweaked every single day.  You may see a change in your ranking, that lasts a couple of months and then returns to where it was before.  It's not unheard of for Google to say, "that idea didn't work, we'll remove it."  Or they could keep it and change it some more.  All that is to say that SEO is not some secret formula that says "Do X and you'll automatically outrank all of your competition".  Google's ultimate goal is to provide the best possible answer to the user's query - as determined by the user's response, not our own opinion of our own content.