Why would Google not index a[n. IMHO, perfectly good] webpage?
I have a page in my website that Google does not crawl, though

Browsing the URL renders the page correctly, with no errors in Chrome console.
The URL doesn't contain any special characters, just a-z, an underscore, and a dot preceding the html suffix.
It passes HTML validation.
It has a correct canonical.
It does not have HTML / http robots tag at all, much the less with noindex.
Is in the sitemap.xml, and none of the URLs in it have a priority.
It is linked by several dozen other pages in the website, which Google has indexed.
Google Console lists it under "Discovered - currently not indexed" for a while.
I have requested it to be index several times via Google Console.
It's original content I wrote myself, and searching for text from the page in Google doesn't find any duplicates.
Newer pages were indexed within a couple of days.


How long have you been waiting, how big is your site, and how many clicks away is it from the homepage?

@RichardB It's 3 clicks from the home page, my site has ~200 pages, and I have been waiting ~2 months.

How old is your site, not just the page?  Is there any reason for Google to doubt the veracity of the content?  Take a look at the E.A.T. issues here https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131429/whats-after-ranking-with-low-difficulty-keyword/131473#131473

It depends. What is the content about?
